# splitting field of $(x^2-3)(x^2-5)$ over $Q(\sqrt{ 2})$. Am I thinking of this correctly?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Okay so I just started working on splitting fields today and I wanted to make sure that I understand it well. Here is a specific question I've been working on...

Construct the splitting field for the polynomial $(x
^2 − 3)(x
^2 − 5)$ over $Q(\sqrt{
2})$. What is
the degree of the extension? Why?

here is my work, if there's any mistakes no matter how nitty gritty (or glaringly obvious) I would very much so appreciate having these pointed out and if anyone thinks there's a faster or neater way to show anything I try to show here then I would very much so be grateful for such suggestions as well.

$(x^2-3)(x^2-5)=(x-\sqrt{3})(x+\sqrt{3})(x-\sqrt{5})(x+\sqrt{5})$

so the roots of the original polynomial are $+-\sqrt{3}$ and $+-\sqrt{5}$

these roots are not elements of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ as we shall prove thusly

elements of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ are of the form $\{a+b\sqrt{2}|a,b \in \Bbb Q\}$ so if we were to have $\sqrt{3}$ as an element of this then it would imply that:

$3= a^2+ab\sqrt{2}+2b^2$

which has three cases

1) $ab \neq 0 \Rightarrow ab=\frac{3-a^2-2b^2}{\sqrt{2}}$ which is impossible as  $ab \in \Bbb Q$ so it cant have an irrational denominator.

2) $a=0 \Rightarrow 3=2b^2 \Rightarrow b=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$ again impossible as $b \in \Bbb Q$

3)$b=0 \Rightarrow a=\sqrt{3}$ again impossible as $a \in \Bbb Q$

so we have shown $ \sqrt{3} \notin \Bbb Q(\sqrt{2}) $
therefore we seek an extension of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ which does contain these roots.

By the irreducibility test we know that $x^2-3$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})[x]$ as we shown that $\sqrt{3}$( the root of that polynomial) is not an element of that field. so we conclude:

$\Bbb Q(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{2}) \cong \Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})[x]/<x^2-3>$ and so $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{2}):= \{a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}+d\sqrt{6}|a.b.c.d. \in \Bbb Q \}$

Next lets show that $\sqrt{5}$ is not an element of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{2})$

suppose it is

$\Rightarrow 5= a^2+2b^2+3c^2+6d^2+2ab\sqrt{2}+2ac\sqrt{3}+(2ad+2bc)\sqrt{6}+2bd\sqrt{12}+2cd\sqrt{18}$

in seeking to get rid of all the square roots we have 4 cases.

1)$a=0, b=0, c=0 \Rightarrow d=\sqrt{\frac{5}{6}}$ impossible as $d \in \Bbb Q$

we obtain similar results for case 2 where a=0, c=0, d= 0 and case 3 where a=0 , b= o, d=0 and case 4 where b=0, c=0, d=0.

so we conclude $\sqrt{5} \notin \Bbb Q(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{2})$ so we also need to adjoin this element on.

by the irreduciblity test we that $x^2-5$ is irreducible in $Q(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})[x]$ as we have shown that its root is not an element of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$

so we conclude

$\Bbb Q(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{5}) \cong \Bbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})[x]/<x^2-5>$

so our splitting field is $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})$ which is of the form $\{a+b\sqrt{5}+c\sqrt{2}+d\sqrt{10}+e\sqrt{3}+f\sqrt{15}+g\sqrt{6}+g\sqrt{30} |a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h \in \Bbb Q \}$ and by tower law is a degree 4 extension over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$

Comment: In your 'big expression' where you show that $5$ isn't a square of an element in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$, neither $\sqrt{12}$ nor $\sqrt{18}$ is in primitive form.

Comment: so the primitive forms of these are $\sqrt{12}=2 \sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{18}=3 \sqrt{2}$ cleaning up the expresion for 5=... and then repeating that part with my new cleaned up expresion. Is the rest okay apart from that ?

Comment: Assuming that you've showed that $a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}+d\sqrt{6}=0\implies a=b=c=d=0$ then I think so, but note that cleaning up your expression for 5 will lead to a somewhat more complicated argument there.

Comment: In proving $\sqrt{5}\notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$, why do you only have those four cases where three of $a,b,c,d$ are 0?

Comment: @Delong what other cases would there be ?, I'm eliminating all of the coefficients of the terms involving roots.

Comment: @exodius for example, all of them can be non-zero.

Comment: @Delong good point, I should add an extra case too allow for this :)